# Separar uma coluna do banco em duas e pegar os valores dos usuarios já criados

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Tenho um tabela de usuários no banco que consta com uma coluna NOME, porém será necessário separar entre NOME e SOBRENOME.
A minha dúvida é: os usuários já criados no banco terão que ser editados um a um? Ou tem algum comando que eu possa quebrar o nome do usuário em dois e jogar a segunda parte do nome para a nova coluna SOBRENOME??

Atualmente:  Nome: Rodrigo Barreto
Objetivo: Nome: Rodrigo , Sobrenome: Barreto

Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 2):

**S**im, você tem algumas [**funções para string**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) que fazem isso:

*Exemplo:*

```
select
    substring(trim(nome)  from 0 for position(' ' in trim(nome))) as firstname,
    substring(trim(nome) from position(' ' in trim(nome)) for char_length(trim(nome))) as lastname
from usuarios
where trim(nome) like '% %';
```

> **Dados de exemplo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloquei no [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3917d/2)

O Comando de update ficaria assim:

```
update usuarios set 
    nome = substring(trim(nome)  from 0 for position(' ' in trim(nome))),
    sobrenome  = substring(trim(nome) from position(' ' in trim(nome)) for char_length(trim(nome)))
where sobrenome is null and trim(nome) like '% %';
```

> Ps. O código pode te facilitar, mas dará problemas quando for um nome composto ou não tiver um sobrenome. Exemplo: "João Paulo", ou "Fulano"

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que sua estrutura de dados seja algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_usuario
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    nome_completo TEXT,
    nome TEXT,
    sobrenome TEXT
);
```

Dados de Teste:

```
-- DADOS PARA TESTE
INSERT INTO tb_usuario ( id, nome_completo ) VALUES ( 1, 'Rodrigo Barreto Silva' );
INSERT INTO tb_usuario ( id, nome_completo ) VALUES ( 2, 'Dino da Silva Sauro' );
INSERT INTO tb_usuario ( id, nome_completo ) VALUES ( 3, 'Bond James Bond' );
INSERT INTO tb_usuario ( id, nome_completo ) VALUES ( 4, 'Raimundo Nonato Santos' );
```

Você pode usar um `UPDATE` sem cláusula `WHERE` usando as funções `substr()` e `split_part()` combinadas para resolver o seu problema:

```
-- ATUALIZANDO TABELA
UPDATE
    tb_usuario
SET
    nome = split_part( nome_completo, ' ', 1 ),
    sobrenome = substr( nome_completo, length(split_part( nome_completo, ' ', 1 ) ) + 2 );
```

Consultado dados atualizados:

```
-- TABELA ATUALIZADA
SELECT 
    nome_completo,
    nome,
    sobrenome
FROM
    tb_usuario;
```

Saída:

```
|          nome_completo |     nome |      sobrenome |
|------------------------|----------|----------------|
|  Rodrigo Barreto Silva |  Rodrigo |  Barreto Silva |
|    Dino da Silva Sauro |     Dino | da Silva Sauro |
|        Bond James Bond |     Bond |     James Bond |
| Raimundo Nonato Santos | Raimundo |  Nonato Santos |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5aafb/1